# Is there a management url that lists all existing servlets in Apache Sling or CQ?

Tags: url, sling

I am wandering if I can get a management url to show all the existing servlets. Could anyone help me on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful, because pages & components effectively servlets themselves.

Also, OSGi-installed servlets can respond to either a path, or to a resource type.  For more information, checkout [SCR Annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/extending-scr-annotations.html) `@Property()` for `sling.servlet.[paths, methods, selectors, resourceTypes]`

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate all OSGi services which are Servlets, but this gives you only part of the picture as Sling also tries to find scripts at locations that match the current request (resource type, extension, selectors etc), and wraps them as Servlets on the fly.

The /system/console/servletresolver webconsole plugin is probably the closest that you can get to this, but you'll need to call that for all the paths that are relevant to you.